# What is the best way to implement an accelerometer with existing Modbus equipment and limited ADC resolution?

Tags: arduino, adc

I need to find the easiest and cheapest way to add an accelerometer to my current set up.

I only need to detect local disturbences that will affect the weighing process that I am carrying out.

My current set up uses LabVIEW Community Edition on a PC to control and collect weight data with a load cell that can resolve 2 grams in 100kg, so quite sensitive. The data is collected using Modbus RTU. Other operations are also controlled by Modbus through a [Barth STG-680 PLC.](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/plcs-programmable-logic-controllers/1232106) This has a 0-10V 12bit ADC so expecting 4096 levels. I have tried using an [ADXL335 accelerometer](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adxl335.pdf) wired directly into the PLC but it is not sensitive enough as the voltage range is 0-3.5V and so only uses 1352 levels of the 4096 available on the PLC.

I have thought of getting an Arduino UNO R4 Minima which can be set to 14 bit ADC giving 16383 levels over 5V so 11468 levels in the 3.5V range. I would then have to spend time with the Arduino code and find out how to get the data with LabVIEW or add a Modbus shield. I am not sure if that works with the R4 Minima.

Another alternative might be to get a SM24 geophone which may be more sensitive than the ADXL335 but that seems to run on 5V also so not much advantage to wiring it to the PLC.

My third guess is to get or make a board with high bit ADC and Modbus RTU capability but I haven't found one yet or a circuit diagram.

- [STG-680](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/plcs-programmable-logic-controllers/1232106)
- [ADXL335](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adxl335.pdf)

Comment: Rather than hacking something together with an Arduino, an ADC and some home grown code, you might consider a complete commercially available accelerometer with a Modbus connection.  That's the same thing you are considering with the Arduino and the Modbus shield, with the difference that it has known (or at least specified) performance.

Comment: Yes, that would be nice but I havent seen anything for less that $300 or £

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *This has a 0-10V 12bit ADC so expecting 4096 levels. I have tried
> using an ADXL335 accelerometer wired directly into the PLC but it is
> not sensitive enough as the voltage range is 0-3.5V and so only uses
> 1352 levels of the 4096 available on the PLC.*

Use a precision op-amp powered from (say) 12 volts to raise the 0 to 3.5 volt input to the required 0 to 10 volts input level. Whether this is good enough to meet your needs is unknown to me but, it will certainly improve the resolution of your readings by nearly 3 times.

Maybe consider the [ADA4522](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/609/ada4522_1_4522_2_4522_4-3120793.pdf) <-- first device that sprang to mind but there may be more appropriate choices.

Comment: Thats a great suggestion, I have looked at amplifier theory and there is so many aspects to it. Have you seen a suitable circuit diagram that would give me 0-10v output?

Comment: Use an op-amp like the ADA4522 I linked. You can buy it as a module also (circa £30). If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.